# React re-render problem with same data but different object of API

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am hitting a backend API which contains array of objects. I am storing the API data in a state called `reportsTabData`. This state contains array of objects and one object who's key is reports contains array of objects called `options` and each options contains array of objects called `fields`. I am setting the `fields` array of objects in my state called `optionsTabData` and I am creating a UI based on optionsTabData.

Example:

```
[
  ..some objects,
  {
    key: "report",
    default: "incoming"
    options: [
      {
        type: "incoming",
        fields: [
          {
            colspan: "1"
            key: "CLAppSchedulerRepDependentSelectors"
            label: "Extension(s) Selection"
            type: "CLAppSchedulerRepDependentSelectors"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        type: "outgoing",
        fields: [
          {
            colspan: "1"
            key: "CLAppSchedulerRepDependentSelectors"
            label: "Extension(s) Selection"
            type: "CLAppSchedulerRepDependentSelectors"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The code works fine and UI is generated, but as you see, there are some reports who's fields contain same objects. The problem is the state update is not re-rendering for such use-case else it works fine.

Below is the code:

```
const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);
const [optionsTabData, setOptionsTabData] = useState([]);
```

```
useEffect(() => {
  callForApi()
},[])
```

```
  const callForApi = async () => {
    setLoader(true);
    let response = await getRequest("api-url");
    if (response.status == 200 && response.status <= 300) {
      let adapter = response.data.schema;
      setAdapterData(adapter);
      setReportsTabData(adapter.report.fields);
      setDistributionTabData(adapter.distribution.fields);
      let data = [];
      for (const ele of adapter.report.fields) {
        if (ele.key === "report") {
          for (const item of ele.options) {
            if (item.type === ele.default) {
              data = [...item.fields];
              break;
            }
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      setOptionsTabData(data);
    } else {
      toastErrorMessagePopUp(response.data.detail);
    }
    setLoader(false);
  };
```

```
  const handleDropdownChange = (key, value) => {
    if (key === "report") {
      const schema = [...reportsTabData];
      let report = schema.find((ele) => ele.key === "report");
      let newOptions = []
      for (const ele of report.options) {
        if (ele.type === value) {
          newOptions=[...ele.fields];
          break;
        }
      }
      setOptionsTabData([...newOptions])
    }
  }
```

How do I solve this? Apparently, doing something like `await setOptionsTabData([])` before `setOptionsTabData([...newOptions])` solves it but I think using await is a bad idea and also the value reflecting after a click in dropdown is sluggish and slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can "force" the re-render by using a combination of `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

```
setOptionsTabData(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newOptions)))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but this is not working :(

Comment: hmm this is weird since json.parse creates a new object so it should trigger the re-render

Comment: Exactly my thought, I am just wondering why does the code with ```await setOptionsTabData([ ])``` before setting the new array of objects works? Also, its sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should be working. You are passing new array to `setOptionsTabData` which should trigger a rerender.

Using `await` is not a solution - functions returned by useState are synchronous and that should not make a difference. What's actually happening is you are resetting your optionsData state to an empty array and then setting it to the desired data.

Is there more code you can show? Maybe you have a `useEffect` somewhere that updates your UI with unfulfilled dependencies?

Comment: Yes, since it wasn't working, I was setting it to [ ] array before setting it to desired data - which is dirty and I am just using useEffect for making the API call when the component mounts. So basically, ```reportsTabData``` state is set from the API.

Comment: Could show more code please? Specifically code related to `setOptionsTabData` It will be easier to tell.

Comment: Sure! Updated my question with more relevant code.